# Idiom/expression for "responsible for what happened."

Tags: expressions, idioms

Example:

> I doubt the kids are responsible for what happened.

What idiom/expression can I use to replace the *responsible for what happened* part? Something that isn't as straight forward as the example.

Comment: What @medica said. Just what do you want to communicate? Depending on the context (e.g., if there is a fault), other expressions to use here might be *I doubt that the kids are to blame* and *I doubt that it is their fault.*

Comment: 'I can't see the kids being involved.'

Comment: The kids didn't do it.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=afam2nIae4o

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the context; [guilty](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Guilty) can convey the idea if something bad or illegal  has been done.

> - Responsible for a reprehensible act; culpable.

Source: www.thefreedictionary.com